# Segmentation Fault when creating a queued list of objects

Tags: c, pointers, object, linked-list

Task is to create objects in the `main` and have them passed to other functions, which will create a **list** of type **queue**. That's the algorithm I'm using:

- Write a function of type `Node *` which will `return` a pointer to the last `Node` of the **list**
- To insert a `Node` at the end of the **list**, it's required to get a pointer to the last `Node`
- Create a new `Node`
- Assign the newly created `Node` the object that's been passed to the function
- Make `next` from the last `Node` point the new one

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct Node{
int val;
char str[30];
struct Node *next;
}Node;

void printList(const Node * head);
void queue(Node *head, Node *object);
Node *getLast(Node *head);

int main(void){

Node *head = NULL;
Node *object = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
int c = 0;
while(1){
    printf("This int will be stored in Node %d.\n", ++c);
    scanf("%d", &object->val);
    if(!object->val){
        puts("You've decided to stop adding Nodes.");
        break;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("This string will be stored in Node %d.\n", c);
    fgets(object->str, 30, stdin);
    if(!(strcmp(object->str, "\n\0"))){
        puts("You've decided to stop adding Nodes.");
        break;
    }


queue(head, object);


}
printList(head);

return 0;
}

void printList(const Node *head){
if(head == NULL){
    puts("No list exists.");
    exit(1);
}
while(1){

    printf("|||Int: %d|||String: %s|||\n", head->val, head->str);

    if(head->next){
        head = head->next;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
}

Node *getLast(Node *head){
if(head == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
while(head->next){
    head = head ->next;
}
return head;
}

void queue(Node *head, Node *object){
Node *last = getLast(head);
Node *tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
*tmp = *object;
tmp -> next = NULL;
last -> next = tmp;
}
```

Maybe the problem is in having `getLast` `return` `NULL`. But then again, this exact same thing worked when I created a **list** consisting only of `int`.

Comment: I doubt that it worked without the string. For the first element you call `getlast` and it returns `NULL`. Then you access the memory `last->next = tmp`; This is UB and will likely crash. It doesn't matter if it is an integer or an integer and a string in the node.

Comment: You allocate only *one* node. (outside the loop)

Comment: What does the debugger say? You did run it through a debugger, right?

Comment: @Devolus This is what the Online C compiler said: `"Program received signal 0x0000000000400e81 in qn.c: 223 last->next = tmp;"` Visual Studio: `"Exception thrown: read access violation. **head** was 0xCDCDCDCD"` regarding `if(head->next) {` in the `getLast` function.

Comment: That may be, but you surely tried to debug your code to figure out whats wrong with it, before you went here in search of help.

Comment: @Devolus I did try it. For other problems it sometimes helps, but they haven't taught us debugging yet in college, so I don't really know how to use it. Furthermore, I did have an idea `NULL` being returned might have been the problem, but I didn't know how to rewrite the `queue` function, so asking this question was still necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section, `last->next = tmp` fails for first call to queue() as getLast() returns NULL. A correct solution would be like this:

```
  void queue(Node **head, Node *object){                                          
  Node *last = getLast(*head);                                                  
  Node *tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));                                     
  *tmp = *object;                                                               
  tmp -> next = NULL;                                                           

  if (last != NULL)                                                             
    last -> next = tmp;                                                         
  else                                                                          
    *head = tmp;                                                                
}
```

and call `queue(&head, object)` from main().